# Read more functionality: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do a *Read More* functionality, where clicking read more will show the long text for both the header and message. I came across this [solution](https://github.com/Thamodaran/react-read-more-less/blob/master/src/index.js) and works, but this only works for only one long text. I want to only have one read more option for both header and message, so I modified it a bit but I am having the above error.

After reading so many similar questions, I still can't seem to fix my code. I understand that this has something to do with the setting of state, but I am at a lost on how to fix this.

Here is a self-contained sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qwbcb?file=src/App.js

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { notificationsApi } from './fakeAPI';
import ReadMore from './ReadMore';

const Notifications = () => {
  const [notifs, setNotifs] = useState(null);

  const Lists = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const notif = await notificationsApi.getNotifications();
      setNotifs(notif);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    // return () => {
    //   notifs;
    // };
  }, [notifs]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Lists();
  }, [Lists]);

  return (
    <Box>
      {notifs &&
        notifs.map((notif) => {
          return (
            <Box key={notif.id}>
              <ReadMore
                headerLimit={112}
                messageLimit={298}
                isRead={notif.isRead}
                headerNotif={notif.header}
                messageNotif={notif.message}
              />
            </Box>
          );
        })}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Notifications;
```

**ReadMore.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const ReadMore = (props) => {
  const { headerNotif, messageNotif, isRead, headerLimit, messageLimit } =
    props;
  const [header, setHeader] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState({
    headLimit: headerLimit,
    messLimit: messageLimit,
  });
  const [initialHeaderLimit] = useState(headerLimit);
  const [initialMessageLimit] = useState(messageLimit);
  const [showOption, setShowOption] = useState(false);
  const [viewMoreClicked, setViewMoreClicked] = useState(false);

  const getReadMoreContent = () => {
    if (headerNotif.length > limit.headLimit) {
      setHeader(<span>{headerNotif.substr(0, limit.headLimit)}...</span>);
      setShowOption(true);
    } else if (headerNotif.length < limit.headLimit) {
      setHeader(<span>{headerNotif}</span>);
    }

    if (messageNotif.length > limit.messLimit) {
      setMessage(
        <span>
          {messageNotif.substr(0, limit.messLimit)}...
          {!viewMoreClicked && (
            <Box sx={{ pt: 2 }}>
              <span
                style={{
                  color: '#008C44',
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  display: 'block',
                  fontSize: 14,
                }}
                onClick={() => showLongText()}
              >
                <u> View More</u>
              </span>
            </Box>
          )}
        </span>
      );
      setShowOption(true);
    } else if (messageNotif.length < limit.messLimit) {
      setMessage(<span>{messageNotif}</span>);
    }

    return (
      <span>
        <Box sx={{ pb: 1 }}>
          <Typography
            variant="subtitle2"
            style={{
              fontSize: 16,
              color: isRead ? '#333333' : '#008C44',
            }}
          >
            {header}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ pb: 1 }}>
          <Typography
            variant="body2"
            style={{
              fontSize: 12,
              color: '#666666',
            }}
          >
            {message}
          </Typography>
        </Box>

        <span
          style={{
            color: '#008C44',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            display: 'block',
            fontSize: 14,
          }}
          onClick={() => showShortText()}
        >
          {showOption && viewMoreClicked && <u> View Less</u>}
        </span>
      </span>
    );
  };

  const showLongText = () => {
    setViewMoreClicked(true);
    setLimit({
      headLimit: headerNotif.length,
      messLimit: messageNotif.length,
    });
    getReadMoreContent();
  };

  const showShortText = () => {
    setViewMoreClicked(false);
    setLimit({
      headLimit: initialHeaderLimit,
      messLimit: initialMessageLimit,
    });
    getReadMoreContent();
  };

  return <>{getReadMoreContent()}</>;
};

ReadMore.propTypes = {
  headLimit: PropTypes.number,
  messLimit: PropTypes.number,
};

export default ReadMore;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up redoing the `ReadMore.jsx` to limit the use of states and did conditional returns:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'

const Content = (
    header,
    message,
    isRead,
    showLongText,
    showShortText,
    showViewMore,
    showViewLess
) => {
    return (
        <span>
            <Box sx={{ pb: 1 }}>
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle2"
                    style={{
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: isRead ? '#333333' : '#008C44',
                    }}
                >
                    {header}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ pb: 1 }}>
                <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    style={{
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: '#666666',
                    }}
                >
                    {message}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
            {showViewMore && (
                <Box sx={{ pt: 2 }}>
                    <span
                        style={{
                            color: '#008C44',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            display: 'block',
                            fontSize: 14,
                        }}
                        onClick={() => showLongText()}
                    >
                        <u> View More</u>
                    </span>
                </Box>
            )}
            {showViewLess && (
                <Box sx={{ pt: 2 }}>
                    <span
                        style={{
                            color: '#008C44',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            display: 'block',
                            fontSize: 14,
                        }}
                        onClick={() => showShortText()}
                    >
                        <u> View Less</u>
                    </span>
                </Box>
            )}
        </span>
    )
}

const ReadMore = (props) => {
    const { headerNotif, messageNotif, isRead, headerLimit, messageLimit } =
        props
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState({
        headLimit: headerLimit,
        messLimit: messageLimit,
    })

    const getReadMoreContent = () => {
        if (headerNotif.length > limit.headLimit) {
            if (messageNotif.length > limit.messLimit) {
                return Content(
                    headerNotif.substr(0, limit.headLimit) + '...',
                    messageNotif.substr(0, limit.messLimit) + '...',
                    isRead,
                    showLongText,
                    showShortText,
                    true,
                    false
                )
            } else if (messageNotif.length < limit.messLimit) {
                return Content(
                    headerNotif.substr(0, limit.headLimit) + '...',
                    messageNotif,
                    isRead,
                    showLongText,
                    showShortText,
                    true,
                    false
                )
            }
        } else if (headerNotif.length < limit.headLimit) {
            if (messageNotif.length > limit.messLimit) {
                return Content(
                    headerNotif,
                    messageNotif.substr(0, limit.messLimit) + '...',
                    isRead,
                    showLongText,
                    showShortText,
                    true,
                    false
                )
            } else if (messageNotif.length < limit.messLimit) {
                return Content(
                    headerNotif,
                    messageNotif,
                    isRead,
                    showLongText,
                    showShortText,
                    false,
                    false
                )
            }
        }

        return Content(
            headerNotif,
            messageNotif,
            isRead,
            showLongText,
            showShortText,
            false,
            true
        )
    }

    const showLongText = () => {
        setLimit({
            headLimit: headerNotif.length,
            messLimit: messageNotif.length,
        })
        getReadMoreContent()
    }

    const showShortText = () => {
        setLimit({
            headLimit: headerLimit,
            messLimit: messageLimit,
        })
        getReadMoreContent()
    }

    return <>{getReadMoreContent()}</>
}

export default ReadMore
```